# Segue anachronism

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to pass text input from the following ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        inputField.delegate = self

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        inputField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(inputField: UITextField) {
        let info = inputField.text
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToBlue", sender: info)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToBlue" {     
            if let blueVC = segue.destinationViewController as? BlueViewController {                
                if let sentValue = sender as? String {
                    blueVC.receptacle = sentValue
                    print(blueVC.receptacle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To this ViewController:

```
class BlueViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var blueText: UILabel!
    var receptacle = "fail"

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(receptacle)
        blueText.text = receptacle
        print(receptacle)
    }
}
```

The `print` statement in the first ViewController outputs correctly, however the output for the `print` statements in the second ViewController is `fail` `fail`, and the label in the second view reads "fail".

Due to this, I have reason to believe this is a timing issue.

Am I right? How do I fix this?

Comment: You code works for me.  How exactly did you wire up your segue?

Comment: from the the text field referenced as inputField to the BlueViewController @vacawama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger your segue programmatically, you need to wire your `goToBlue` segue from the *ViewController* icon of your *from* ViewController to the *BlueViewController*:

[image: how to wire the segue]

Remember to set the *Identifier* of the *Storyboard Segue* in the *Attributes Inspector* to `goToBlue`.

Comment: Wow that worked. Why doesn't it work from the textField? @vacawama

Comment: This is the warning I get when I wired it from the input field.  Warning: Attempt to present <SOSegueProblem.BlueViewController: 0x7fb7e8497600> on <SOSegueProblem.ViewController: 0x7fb7e8617680> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I've always seen that you need to wire it like I showed if you want to call the segue programmatically.

Comment: I got that error too, but didn't understand it. Thanks

Comment: The lunar eclipse has started if you're on the dark side of the earth and have clear skies.